# Sorting data dynamically based upon key names and value combos

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, key, key-value

So, I'll begin by saying that I'm terrible at programming.  However, I've been exposed to enough *good* programmers that I feel like there must be a more elegant solution to what I'm attempting to do - I hope maybe someone here will know of one.

I am trying to find a good way to sort data (that I have little control over).  The data is passed as an array of dicts -- all identically defined -- and I will be sorting based upon the following criteria:

- Any key name may possess a specific property, such as beginning with a special character (in this example, an "o")
- One or more keys within a single dict may possess this property
- If the property is present, group these dicts together where **all** values of keys possessing the property are identical
- The order that data is presented and returned is not significant

For example, given the following input data in dict format:

```
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
| o_last | first   | o_zip |    likes     |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
| Smith  | Bob     | 12345 | Apples       |
| Smith  | Alice   | 12345 | Peaches      |
| Smith  | Marvin  | 54321 | Strawberries |
| Jones  | Steve   | 98765 | Potatoes     |
| Jones  | Harold  | 98765 | Beets        |
| White  | Carol   | 00001 | Fish         |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
```

The following groups would be output:

```
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
| Smith  | Bob     | 12345 | Apples       |
| Smith  | Alice   | 12345 | Peaches      |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+

+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
| Smith  | Marvin  | 54321 | Strawberries |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+

+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
| Jones  | Steve   | 98765 | Potatoes     |
| Jones  | Harold  | 98765 | Beets        |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+

+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
| White  | Carol   | 00001 | Fish         |
+--------+---------+-------+--------------+
```

Below is the current function I have in place to achieve this, and so far it seems to work fine.  However, as I mention above, I have to believe there is a more elegant library or design pattern I'm unaware of that could be used.

```
def sort_data(input_d):

    fields = []
    has_prop = False
    prop_fields = []
    prop_dict = {}
    out_list = []

    # create a list of keys that have the property
    [fields.append(x) for x in input_d[0].keys()]
    for field in fields:
        if re.match("^o[a-np-zA-NP-Z]*_", field):
            has_prop = True
            prop_fields.append(field)

    # if keys are found:
    if has_prop:
        for d in input_d:
            prop_vals = ""
            for f in prop_fields:
                prop_vals += d[f]

            # create an md5 hash of unique values for keys with property
            # and use it to group dicts with the same value combinations
            prop_vals_hash = hashlib.md5(prop_vals).hexdigest()
            if prop_vals_hash in prop_dict:
                prop_dict[prop_vals_hash].append(d)
            else:
                prop_dict[prop_vals_hash] = [d]

        # return data as an array of arrays, with each index
        # in that array a grouping of dicts with unique value combinations
        for k in prop_dict.keys():
            out_list.append(prop_dict[k])

    # default for input data that does not have keys possessing 
    # our property of interest
    else:
        for d in input_d:
            output_list.append([d])

    return output_list
```

I would love to hear any and all replies, suggestions, criticism or feedback that anyone is willing to provide.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: From what you say, it sounds like your dicts represent a tabular structure (with each dict being a row in the table).  If that is the case, you should look at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, which provides many useful tools for working with tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to understand whether records with all prop fields identical can be assumed to be already sorted next to each other -- I'm going to assume that, because otherwise a sorting will be needed and I can't guess at the sorting criteria you want to use.  So...:

```
output_list = []
prop_fields = [k for k in input_d[0] if k.startswith('o')]

# if keys are found:
if prop_fields:
    for k, g in itertools.group_by(input_d, key=operator.itemgetter(*prop_fields)):
        output_list.append(list(g))
else:
    output_list = [[d] for d in input_d]
return output_list
```

If the "order is fine and must be maintained" condition does not apply, then you must add, right after the `if prop_fields:`

```
input_d.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*prop_fields))
```

but, that would **not** match the order-preserving characteristic of your example (nor, I believe, would your code as you present it).

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to learn from this question, thanks so much for taking the time.  Your assumption was spot on, I do not care about the order, as it is not at all significant.  I have edited the original question to ensure this is more clear.